# How to open a Jquery Dialog popup when checkbox is clicked and restore button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback

My code is somewhat like this:

```
  function ShowPopUpRestore() {
        var returnval = 1;
        var hddnField = document.getElementById(<%=hdnSelectedRows.ClientID%>");
        if (hddnField.value != 0) {
            returnVal = 0;
           $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                                .html('<div><align="left"> </br>' + '<%= this.GetMessage("Msg1595")%>' + '</h6></div>')
                                .dialog({
                                    resizable: false,
                                    modal: true,
                                    title: "",
                                    height: 150,
                                    width: 475,
                                    buttons: {
                                        Yes: function () {
                                           // //__doPostBack(mDdlSurgeryListRE.name, '');

                                            $(this).dialog("close");
                                        },
                                        "No": function () {                                         

                                            $(this).dialog('close');
                                        }
                                    },
                                    close: function (event, ui) {
                                        $(this).remove();
                                    }
                                }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "#4E2D1D");
                            }                            
                    return false;
    }
```

Suppose one of my data is in suspended mode and I want it to be in active mode, so I am trying to restore it via clicking on the restore button.
When I am clicking on the checkbox and trying to click on the restore button, a pop-up should come having a 'yes'/'no' button:

- If I click 'yes', then the data which is checked will be restored back to active mode.
- If I click 'no', then it should remain in suspended mode.

It can be valid for multiple check-boxes(data). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple just create the following events in jQuery and bind them to call ShowPopUpRestore():

1. For the restore button create a `click()` event.
2. For the checkbox create a `change()` event.

**Complete example:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#btnRestore").click(function () {
                ShowPopUpRestore();
            });

            $("#chkBtn").change(function () {
                ShowPopUpRestore();
            });

            function ShowPopUpRestore() {
                var returnval = 1;
                var hddnField = document.getElementById("<%=hdnSelectedRows.ClientID%>");
                if (hddnField.value != 0) {
                    returnVal = 0;
                    $('<div></div>').appendTo('body').html('<div><align="left"></br>' + '<%= this.GetMessage("Msg1595")%>' + '</h6></div>')
                                    .dialog({
                                        resizable: false,
                                        modal: true,
                                        title: "",
                                        height: 150,
                                        width: 475,
                                        buttons: {
                                            Yes: function () {
                                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                                alert('You clicked YES');
                                            },
                                            "No": function () {
                                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                                alert('You clicked NO');
                                            }
                                        },
                                        close: function (event, ui) {
                                            $(this).remove();
                                        }
                                    }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "#4E2D1D");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="button" id="btnRestore" value="Restore" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkBtn" value="Check box" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedRows" runat="server" Value="1" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: when I am clicking on the restore button , then pop up comes and goes within no time. it is not waiting or allowing the user to click on "yes'' / "no" button.

Comment: Then there is some additional logic in YOUR webpage which closes the popup immediately.Copy and paste the code I've posted as is, with no additional logic and you will see that it works.Then once it's working slowly start adding the rest of the code back to the web page

Comment: Hi Denis, I tried doing that but its not working. Is there any alternative solution for this issue.

Comment: I got the answer as i was missing return value in my code first. Thanks